# How to use advance function in swift with three parameters?

Tags: string, function, swift

I was using only advance function by passing two arguments. Can somebody help me to use it with three arguments which is illustrated as:

```
func advance<T : ForwardIndexType>(start: T, n: T.Distance, end: T) -> T
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That function increments the `start` index by `n` positions, but *not
beyond* the `end` index.

**Example:** You want to truncate strings to a given maximal length:

```
func truncate(string : String, length : Int) -> String {
    let index = advance(string.startIndex, length, string.endIndex)
    return string.substringToIndex(index)
}

println(truncate("fooBar", 3)) // foo
println(truncate("fo", 3))     // fo
```

In the first call, the start index is incremented by 3 positions,
in the second example only by two. With

```
let index = advance(string.startIndex, length)
```

the second call would crash with a runtime exception, because
a string index must not be advanced beyond the end index.