# How can split from string to array by chunks of given size

Tags: ios, swift, nsstring, swift4, nsarray

I want to split string  by chunks of given size  `2`

Example :

String `"1234567"` and output should be `["12", "34", "56","7"]`

Comment: What you have tried and what is not working? Unfortunately this is not a code writing service.

Comment: Show your tried code !!

Comment: If you want to split with length of 2 why does the last expected output has 3 characters/integers ? Check this: https://gist.github.com/ericdke/fa262bdece59ff786fcb

Comment: @GoodSp33d I update it should be integer/string  array

Comment: What is the logic behind the last group having 3 elements instead of one?

Comment: @LeoDabus it not 3 or 2 . it's  based on requirement

Comment: Btw you shouldn't edit your question every 5 seconds

Comment: @LeoDabus yea sorry for that .. because  I getting down voted

Comment: If you don't want to get downvotes next time show an attempt to solve your issue

Comment: @LeoDabus that's sound good ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162472/discussion-between-nazmul-hasan-and-leo-dabus).

Comment: Hello Brian! would you give me some explanation why I getting down voted ....

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can group your collection elements (in this case Characters) every n elements as follow:

```
extension Collection {
    func unfoldSubSequences(limitedTo maxLength: Int) -> UnfoldSequence<SubSequence,Index> {
        sequence(state: startIndex) { start in
            guard start < self.endIndex else { return nil }
            let end = self.index(start, offsetBy: maxLength, limitedBy: self.endIndex) ?? self.endIndex
            defer { start = end }
            return self[start..<end]
        }
    }
    func subSequences(of n: Int) -> [SubSequence] {
        .init(unfoldSubSequences(limitedTo: n))
    }
}
```

---

```
let numbers = "1234567"
let subSequences = numbers.subSequences(of: 2)
print(subSequences)    // ["12", "34", "56", "7"]
```

**edit/update**:

If you would like to append the exceeding characters to the last group:

```
extension Collection {
    func unfoldSubSequencesWithTail(lenght: Int) -> UnfoldSequence<SubSequence,Index> {
        let n = count / lenght
        var counter = 0
        return sequence(state: startIndex) { start in
            guard start < endIndex else { return nil }
            let end = index(start, offsetBy: lenght, limitedBy: endIndex) ?? endIndex
            counter += 1
            if counter == n {
                defer { start = endIndex }
                return self[start...]
            } else {
                defer { start = end }
                return self[start..<end]
            }
        }
    }
    func subSequencesWithTail(n: Int) -> [SubSequence] {
        .init(unfoldSubSequencesWithTail(lenght: n))
    }
}
```

---

```
let numbers = "1234567"
let subSequencesWithTail = numbers.subSequencesWithTail(n: 2)
print(subSequencesWithTail)    // ["12", "34", "567"]
```

Comment: Great answer !!

Comment: @LeoDabus `Playground execution failed: error: MyPlayground.playground:6:27: error: argument type 'String' does not conform to expected type 'Sequence'
        let chars = Array(self)`

Comment: If you are using Swift 3. Just change it to `Array(characters)`

Comment: @LeoDabus it's swift4

Comment: Try creating a new playground file and make sure you are using my code as it is.

Answer (score 2):

```
var testString = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstu"
var startingPoint: Int = 0
var substringLength: Int = 1
var substringArray = [AnyHashable]()
for i in 0..<(testString.count ?? 0) / substringLength {
    var substring: String = (testString as NSString).substring(with: NSRange(location: startingPoint, length: substringLength))
    substringArray.append(substring)
    startingPoint += substringLength
}
print("\(substringArray)")
```

OutPut :
(
    a,
    b,
    c,
    d,
    e,
    f,
    g,
    h,
    i,
    j,
    k,
    l,
    m,
    n,
    o,
    p,
    q,
    r,
    s,
    t,
    u
    )

Comment: Code required  in swift

Comment: Here change substringLength from 1 to 2.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
func SplitString(stringToBeSplitted:String, By:Int) -> [String]
    {
        var newArray = [String]()
        var newStr = String()
        for char in stringToBeSplitted
        {
            newStr += String(char)
            if newStr.count == By
            {
                newArray.append(newStr)
                newStr = ""
            }

        }
        return newArray
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Swift 5

```
extension Array {
    func chunks(size: Int) -> [[Element]] {
        return stride(from: 0, to: count, by: size).map {
            Array(self[$0 ..< Swift.min($0 + size, count)])
        }
    }
}

extension String {
    func chunks(size: Int) -> [String] {
        map { $0 }.chunks(size: size).compactMap { String($0) }
    }
}

let s = "1234567"
print(s.chunks(size: 2)) // ["12", "34", "56", "7"]
```

Comment: Tweak: the body of `String.chunks` could also start  with `Array(self).`, instead of `map { $0 }.` Or did you write this intentionally?

Comment: Both create an array of Character, apparently no difference, but maybe Array(self) is optimized for string size, I don’t know.

Comment: Indeed, I've opted to use the Array initialiser for this reason. Also, imo it's slightly more readable and 'consistent' with the other chunks implementation.

Answer (score 1):

```
extension String {
    func split(len: Int) -> [String] {
        var currentIndex = 0
        var array = [String]()
        let length = self.characters.count
        while currentIndex < length {
            let startIndex = self.startIndex.advancedBy(currentIndex)
            let endIndex = startIndex.advancedBy(len, limit: self.endIndex)
            let substr = self.substringWithRange(Range(start: startIndex, end: endIndex))
            array.append(substr)
            currentIndex += len
        }
        return array
    }
}
```

> "123456789".split(2)
>
> //output: ["12", "34", "56", "78", "9"]

Comment: This does not compile in Swift 4.

Comment: Please refer [Leo Dabus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48089097/5523205) accepted answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

I have write one method in objective c as below,

```
-(NSMutableArray*)splitString : (NSString*)str withRange : (int)range{


NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

NSMutableString *mutableStr = [[NSMutableString alloc]initWithString:str];

int j = 0;
int counter = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {

    j++;

    if (range == j) {

        j = 0;


        if (!(i == str.length - 1)) {

             [mutableStr insertString:@"$" atIndex:i+1+counter];
        }



        counter++;
    }
}



arr = (NSMutableArray*)[mutableStr componentsSeparatedByString:@"$"];

NSLog(@"%@",arr);

return arr;
}
```

You can call this method like,

```
 [self splitString:@"123456" withRange:2];
```

and result will be,

```
(
12,
34,
56
)
```

Comment: The questions is tagged Swift.

Comment: Yes I know, I have just write for reference if it is helpful @rmaddy

Answer (score 1):

You can also try below code:

```
var arrStr: [Substring] = []
    let str = "1234567"
    var i = 0
    while i < str.count - 1 {
        let index = str.index(str.startIndex, offsetBy: i)
        //Below line gets current index and advances by 2
        let substring = str[index..<str.index(index, offsetBy: 2)]
        arrStr.append(substring)
        i += 2
    }
    if str.count % 2 == 1 {
        arrStr.append(str.suffix(1))
    }
    print(arrStr)
```

Comment: please add expiation flowing line : `let index = str.index(str.startIndex, offsetBy: i)
        let firstCharacter = str[index..<str.index(index, offsetBy: 2)]`

Comment: @NazmulHasan I have edited my post. Please have a look.

Answer (score 1):

There's a stupid way, you can think about the rules of the data model.

```
    var strOld = "123456"
    print("The original string:\(strOld)")

    strOld.insert("、", at: strOld.index(before: strOld.index(strOld.startIndex, offsetBy: 3)))

    strOld.insert("、", at: strOld.index(before: strOld.index(strOld.startIndex, offsetBy: 6)))

    print("After inserting:\(strOld)")

    let str = strOld

    let splitedArray = str.components(separatedBy: "、")
    print("After the split of the array:\(splitedArray)")

    let splitedArrayOther = str.split{$0 == "、"}.map(String.init)
    print("After break up the array (method 2):\(splitedArrayOther)")
```

The results:

```
The original string:123456
After inserting:12、34、56
After the split of the array:["12", "34", "56"]
After break up the array (method 2):["12", "34", "56"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a short (and clean) solution, thanks to recursion:

```swift
extension Collection {
    func chunks(ofSize size: Int) -> [SubSequence] {
        // replace this by `guard count >= size else { return [] }`
        // if you want to omit incomplete chunks
        guard !isEmpty else { return [] }
        return [prefix(size)] + dropFirst(size).chunks(ofSize: size)
    }
}
```

The recursion should not pose a performance problem, as Swift has support for tail call optimization.

Also if Swift arrays are really fast when it comes to prepending or appending elements (like the Objective-C ones are), then the array operations should be fast.

Thus you get both fast and readable code (assuming my array assumptions are true).