# how can I flip a hex string in iOS swift

Tags: swift, string, hex, reverse

I have a hex string : `81 61 08 0a a0 80 04`

now I want to reverse it like : `04 80 a0 0a 08 61 81`

I have tried converting hex to number and then reversing it and convert back to hex but it doesn't provide the required result.

Comment: You can user like let str = "81 61 08 0a a0 80 04"
print(String(str.reversed()))

Comment: @KishanBhatiya did you check you code? I guess print will be "40 08 0a a0 80 16 18"

Comment: yes that was print "40 08 0a a0 80 16 18" @VadimNikolaev

Comment: @KishanBhatiya Then you need to read the question again

Comment: @KishanBhatiya but the expected result is different - `04 80 a0 0a 08 61 81`

Comment: Well, Vadim's answer was working also, the expected result is reverse of the string but with a twist :)

Comment: @Rj19 Vadim's answer requires you to import Foundation and initializes a new Array unnecessarily

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply split your collection `String` if the character `isWhitespace`, reverse it and join it back to a `String`:

```
let hex = "81 61 08 0a a0 80 04"
let hexReversed = hex.split(whereSeparator: \.isWhitespace)
                      .reversed()
                      .joined(separator: " ")
print(hexReversed)   // "04 80 a0 0a 08 61 81\n"
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48089097/2303865 just add this extension to your project and `let hexReversed = hex.groups(of: 2).reversed().joined()`

Comment: but its making array not string

Comment: @Rj19 Are you sure? https://www.dropbox.com/s/67uddi8acb5g2tg/groupsOfTwo.jpg?dl=1

Comment: well, just for discussion... I was wondering to handle it using bitwise operator as c language. Isn't it ??

Comment: @Rj19 I have no c language knowledge. I don't know what you mean by using bitwise operator. Show your original code I can try to translate it to Swift