# Trim String before specific character?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a string (`asderwt.qwertyu.zxcvbbnnhg`) and I want to change it to `.qwertyu.zxcvbbnnhg`.

I have tried to do this using the following code:

```
Var str = "asderwt.qwertyu.zxcvbbnnhg"
if let dotRange = str.range(of: ".") {
str.removeSubrange(dotRange.lowerBound..<str.startIndex)
print("AAAAAAAAAA: \(str)")

 }
```

Comment: What is your algorithm here for deciding where to trim? What have you attempted so far? Show your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the first index of the dot and get the substring after that index

```
let str = "asderwt.qwertyu.zxcvbbnnhg"
if let index = str.firstIndex(where: { $0 == "." }) {
    print(str[index...])//.qwertyu.zxcvbbnnhg
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track, but here

```
str.removeSubrange(dotRange.lowerBound..<str.startIndex)
```

the range bounds are in the wrong order. It should be

```
var str = "asderwt.qwertyu.zxcvbbnnhg"
if let dotRange = str.range(of: ".") {
    str.removeSubrange(str.startIndex..<dotRange.lowerBound) // <-- HERE
    print("Result: \(str)") // Result: .qwertyu.zxcvbbnnhg
}
```

You can also use a “partial range”

```
if let dotRange = str.range(of: ".") {
    str.removeSubrange(..<dotRange.lowerBound)
    print("Result: \(str)") // Result: .qwertyu.zxcvbbnnhg
}
```

Or with `firstIndex(of:)` instead of `range(of:)`:

```
if let dotIndex = str.firstIndex(of: ".") {
    str.removeSubrange(..<dotIndex)
    print("Result: \(str)") // Result: .qwertyu.zxcvbbnnhg
}
```

Comment: Can we do this using `stride`  ?

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya: What do you mean? I not see yet how stride would be useful for this task.

Comment: I have seen this answer so https://stackoverflow.com/a/38980231/4601900 I thought that we can also use it here. may be we can't use stride here

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya: There the *length* of the substrings is given, and the result is an *array* of substrings. Here we want to split on (the first occurrence of) a certain character.