# How can i split credit card number to 4x4x4x4 from 16(without textfield)

Tags: swift, string, split, credit-card

for my project I want to show credit card numbers on a template.

From my API i get credit card number like "4242424242424242" but i need to reformat this numbers with space like this "4242 4242 4242 4242".

I read some topics but people always explaining with textfield or something like this. I have 16 chars long string variable and i need to reformat this to 19 chars long string with spaces.

I dont need any validation just want to make string with spaces.

As a result i need to turn this string "4242424242424242" to "4242 4242 4242 4242" this string.

Last edit: First of all thank you for all answers, i am sorry for asking questions that already asked.

Comment: Aren't some amex cards 15 digits?

Comment: @valosip See my answer 
working 15, 16, 19 digit card numbers

Comment: @valosip i was just want to split value for regular cards but thanks to mirzohid-akbarov, now i can split every card.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use replaceingOccurrences(of:with:options:range:) with Regular Expressions:

```
let creditCardNumber = "4242424242424242"// 16 or 15 digit 
let formattedCreditCardNumber = creditCardNumber.replacingOccurrences(of: "(\\d{4})(\\d{4})(\\d{4})(\\d+)", with: "$1 $2 $3 $4", options: .regularExpression, range: nil)
print(formattedCreditCardNumber)// result 4242 4242 4242 4242
```

Some UnionPay cards will be 19 digits:

```
let unionPayCardNumber = "4242424242424242123"
        let formattedUnionPayCardNumber = unionPayCardNumber.replacingOccurrences(of: "(\\d{4})(\\d{4})(\\d{4})(\\d{4})(\\d+)", with: "$1 $2 $3 $4 $5", options: .regularExpression, range: nil)
print(formattedCreditCardNumber)// result 4242 4242 4242 4242 123
```

Comment: I just want to say again, thank you for your great help! works flawlessly

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do this:

First, split the string into substrings of equal lengths of 4, which can be done with this method found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38980231/5133585).

```
extension String {
    func split(by length: Int) -> [String] {
        var startIndex = self.startIndex
        var results = [Substring]()

        while startIndex < self.endIndex {
            let endIndex = self.index(startIndex, offsetBy: length, limitedBy: self.endIndex) ?? self.endIndex
            results.append(self[startIndex..<endIndex])
            startIndex = endIndex
        }

        return results.map { String($0) }
    }
}
```

And then, you can join the split parts with your desired separator:

```
extension String {

    func inserting(_ c: Character, every index: Int) -> String {
        return self.split(by: index).joined(separator: c)
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let formatted = yourString.inserting(" ", every: 4)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, you helped me twice yesterday ^^
hope you have a great day :)

Answer (score -3):

This should work. It is not particularly expandable though.

```
let before = "4242424242424242"
let after = "\(before[0..<4]) \(before[4..<8]) \(before[8..<12]) \(before[12..<16])"
```